# How to stop JTable TableModelListener from firing or listening when specific column on table changed

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have created a `TableModelListener` which listens to specific column. Specifically, columns **2,3,4,5**. Such that when any column from **2-5** has value or `not null`, it will take and add the values store to a `BigDecimal` value to get the **sum**. After that, I need to set the value of the 6th column to the sum of values of columns **2-5**. So I thought I can simply collect the values then if it encounters column **6**, it will set the sum.

Here's the code.

```
@Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) e.getSource();
        if (tableModel.getRowCount() > 0) {
            for (int row = 0; row < tableModel.getRowCount(); row++) {
                BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                for (int col = 0; col < tableModel.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                    if (col == 2 || col == 3 || col == 4 || col == 5) {
                        if (tableModel.getValueAt(row, col) != null) {
                            sum = sum.add(new BigDecimal(Double.parseDouble(tableModel.getValueAt(row, col).toString())));
                        }
                    } 
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sum: "+sum);
                tableModel.setValueAt(sum, row, 6);
            }
        }
    }
```

So what happens is I get an infinite `JOptionPane Dialog` with the value of sum.
I researched online and thought that maybe after editing I could terminate the listener by adding `view.getMyJTable().putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true);`

Didn't help. I basically just want to be able to get the sum of columns 2-5 whether or not the columns has value that is why I initialized the `BigDecimal` to `ZERO`

It appears to be listening table model changes even on 6th column. I don't know how to select specific columns where the `tablechanged` will apply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've already solved my problem. Sorry for asking this. The solution was simple. I did some research and found a method called `e.getColumn()`

Thanks anyway for viewing my question.

```
@Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        int colChanged = e.getColumn();
        if (colChanged == 2|| colChanged == 3 || colChanged == 4 || colChanged == 5) {
            DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) e.getSource();
            if (tableModel.getRowCount() > 0) {
                for (int row = 0; row < tableModel.getRowCount(); row++) {
                    BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                    for (int col = 0; col < tableModel.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                        if (col == 2 || col == 3 || col == 4 || col == 5) {
                            if (tableModel.getValueAt(row, col) != null) {
                                sum = sum.add(new BigDecimal(Double.parseDouble(tableModel.getValueAt(row, col).toString())));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sum: " + sum);
                    tableModel.setValueAt(sum, row, 6);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No worries, it's ok to answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Betlista Thanks. As much as possible I try to exhaust all possible solutions myself before I seek help. :)